# Loft Bed Design - racking going to be a problem?

Tags: design

I am working on a loft bed for my daughter. I drew up some plans and am mid-build, but still working out how everything will attach. I plan on the head and the foot of the bed to each be one piece so it can be moved. The posts are L-shaped, with an filler that the rails will sit on. I'm not worried about weight, but want to reduce racking as much as I can. I purchased zipbolts that screw into a threaded insert I'll bury into my post. To keep hardware from being visible on my upper railings however, I need a different method to attach to posts.  I purchased some bedlock hardware but with only a 3.75" railing, it only has one hook, which upon receiving the hardware, I'm thinking might have some wobble to it.

Wondering if screwing my railings instead into the post opposite the direction they run, given that I have zipbolts providing some pulling force to the main rails, might be pretty stable -- and if not, are there are joinery or hardware ideas that would be invisible, or not look bad. I haven't cut my rail/railing lengths yet, so I could maybe get creative there.

**Added context: word used is cherry. Each board is thicknessed to 1.25". Posts are 3 laminated boards to total 3.75". Main rail is 6" wide, others are 3.75" wide.This is the harware I'm using to attach my main rails to the posts: https://thecraftsupply.com/product/zipbolt-universal-tool-13-2/?sku=423513500&gclid=CjwKCAjw1t2pBhAFEiwA_-A-NCkxKrioAFguMAfIqCWf6My1zKVDUSfxhGD3Yd19E3fZWxrWU5DAdxoCJMkQAvD_BwE

[image: Bed Design]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. We get these sorts of structural queries fairly regularly, and some specifically were relating to bunk beds/loft beds — have you done a search to see if any of the previous ones might give you what you need?

Comment: If none of the previous Q&As has anything specific enough for your requirements potential respondents could do with additional info on how the rest of this structure is put together, which wood(s) you're building from, and the thickness of the structural elements.

Comment: I'm confused on where these zip bolts go. Which way do they run? Where to does the bedlock hardware go? Your drawing is nice but doesn't clarify these details.

Comment: Zip bolts will go into the inside of the long rails and attach to the post. I attempted to show one centered between the dominos in the right post.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I'm not going to put an Answer here (in hopes someone else will) but I will add the keystone general advice for this type of thing: if in doubt, overbuild. 1.25" is pretty beefy and that's good, but I think it's still worth mentioning the species as there's a big difference if this is SPF or one of the common furniture hardwoods.

Comment: It is a bit unclear how everything will be fastened. eg are biscuits and other connections  glued and fasteners are extra, or is the entire thing only screwed?  As a general guideline consider that one screw in a joint is only a hinge point and racking will occur.  To resist it, you need at least two fasteners at each joint, (top and bottom).  The further you spread them in each joint the better job they can do of keeping the verticals and horizontals perpendicular.  If the joint is fully glued face to face (not ends)  then the screws are not necessary.

Comment: The head and foot of the bed will each be a panel, all horizontal pieces on those are glued and screwed to the posts.

The bottom support spanning the long side would have a biscuit and a zipbolt like this to connect to my posts: 
https://www.woodcraft.com/products/mini-joint-connector-10-800-6mm-x-100mm-2pk-zipbolt

The main 6" wide rails would use these: https://knappconnectors.com/product/zipbolt-90-kd-frame-connectors/

My top railing would connect to the posts with these:
https://www.leevalley.com/en-us/shop/hardware/bed-hardware/connectors/67916-mortise-bedlocks